# Centos 7 - Apache banning my web application security crawler

Tags: ip, centos-7, httpd, web-crawler

I'm trying to run a scan on my website using Vega, but after the crawler has sent a couple of requests my ip address gets blocked for 30 minutes. This is not the fault of fail2ban(which is installed), because it only has a jail for sshd and i've tried turning it off to see if it would help. Could mod_security be the cause?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is not Apache (I doubt it could do temporary blocking out-of-the-box anyway) but some security software that intercepts the scans and blocks you using the server firewall, or some other similar scenario. Do you have any other IDS/IPS installed other than `fail2ban`?

Comment: No, i don't....

Comment: SELinux is disabled too.

Comment: Is this a home setup, or some other network you have full control over yourself (and full knowledge of yourself), or are you in corporate network? When you get your IP blocked, is it just the Apache server that refuses to receive connections, meaning that you can still connect to other resources in the network?

Comment: It's on another network, which i have full control of myself.

Comment: For anyone be able to tell if it is Apache blocking the client, you should provide access and error logs from the time blocking occurs and also provide of your Apache config (at least the relevant parts, sanitised).